# OffsetDateTime with different offsets into OffsetDateTime with UTC (Zulu)

Tags: java, time, java-8, timezone, utc

I have in my database values saved with different offsets, e.g.

```
`2018-03-26T03:00:00+03:00`
`2018-03-26T03:00:00+02:00`
```

I would like to parse them into the `base` value, which should be offset 0, to make an easier comparison but also leaving the date in really human readable (this means I want to stay with Offset, instead of e.g. instant).

How to parse `OffsetDateTime` with an offset into `+00` offset (called `UTC` or `ZULU`) with correct date transfer (I mean, not just changing the 2 into 0, but also calculating the date and time correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s easy when you know how:

```
    String dateTimeFromDatabase = "2018-03-26T03:00:00+03:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeFromDatabase)
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println("With offset 0: " + dateTime);
```

Output is:

> With offset 0: 2018-03-26T00:00Z

I didn’t understand why you minded getting an `Instant`. It prints as `2018-03-26T00:00:00Z`. The only difference is that the seconds are included even though they are `00`.

**Link:** [Documentation of `OffsetDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset))